Can a literal be repeated in SAT or 3SAT?
in the proof here, when reducing from SAT to 3SAT:

I'm confused why so complex, why can't just say if $C$ has one literal $l$,
then let 3SAT just be $l \lor l \lor l$.
Similiarly for $C$ has two literals $l_1$,$l_2$, then just let the clause
be $l_1 \lor l_2 \lor l_1$ ?
So the pratical question is, can a literal be repeated in SAT or 3SAT?
I tried to find the information, wiki just says

A clause is a disjunction of literals (or a single literal).

Nothing says literals needs to be distinct.

The convention may differ. In the foundational paper of Karp, 3SAT is at most 3 literal per clause, but as Wikipedia note it, "Some authors restrict k-SAT to CNF formulas with exactly k literals.", and it shows how the two problems are polynomial time equivalent. It does not really explain why we can't duplicate a literal, but multiple sources I could find online define it properly by defining a clause as a set, or by explicitly stating that the literals must be different.

As pointed in the previous comment, it depends on how you define a clause. If you define it just as a disjunction of three literals a literal can be repeated (since clearly the literal you get is equivalent to the previous one).
For example in the proof that 3SAT is NP-complete in the Sipser's Book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" (that is the corollary 7.42 on page 282 in the second edition) it says: "In each clause that has one or two literals, we replicate one of the literals until the total number is three."
